# Accessors for ECMAScript 5 and higher

Tags: node.js, typescript

**there is  my code :**

```
class Customer {
    private cFirstName: string;
    private cLastName: string;
    constructor(firstname: string, lastname: string) {
        this.cFirstName = firstname;
        this.cLastName = lastname;
    }

    /*Creating Acessors as getters and setters can be
    done this way */


    public get firstName(): string {
        return this.cFirstName;
    }
    public get lastName(): string {
        return this.cLastName;
    }

    public set firstName(fn: string) {
        this.cFirstName = fn;
    }

    public set lastName(ln: string) {
        this.cLastName = ln;
    }

}

let myCustomer5 = new Customer("Leo", "Familiaris");



console.log("*****************************************")
console.log(`the lion scientific name:\n ${myCustomer5.lastName} ${myCustomer5.firstName}  .`);
```

then when i try :

```
$ tsc my_file_name.ts
```

I got those 4 errors
Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher. I'm using Vscode latest and npm 6.13.4 so where are the problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/target.html) greater than ES5. This tells TypeScript which JavaScript runtime version the compiled code will run on. For historical reasons, the default target is `es3` which doesn't support many newer JS features.

You specify the target on the command line with:

```sh
tsc --target es2020 my_file.ts`
```

Or by creating a tsconfig that specifies a target:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020"
    },
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer its clear and work as expected.